# oracle-sql UPDATE if conditions are true in multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have got a problem with an update statement in sql. I want to update param1 in table1 if the conditions are true (shown in my example).

Currently I am trying this:

```
update table1
set table1.param1 = 1
from (select * table1, table2
  where table1.param2=table2.paramA
  and table2.paramB='123456'
  and table1.param3='XXX123');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
update (select * 
        from table1 join table2
        on table1.param2=table2.paramA
        where table2.paramB='123456'
        and table1.param3='XXX123') t
set t.param1 = 1
```

Comment: If I try this I get this Errormessage: 00971. 00000 -  "missing SET keyword"

Comment: please try the modified version.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do join in subquery. You can do the join and update in one go. Please try below query for your update.

```
    update table1 join  table2 on table1.param2=table2.paramA
    set table1.param1 = 1
    where table2.paramB='123456'
    and table1.param3='XXX123';
```

Comment: You can't use `JOIN` in an `UPDATE` in Oracle.